# Speech signal Quality & Speech signal improvement

Tags: speech, speech-processing

I'm trying find authoritative references for

[1] Which analyzing techniques (time/frequency domain) i should use for determining the quality of a speech signal.

[2] Which algorithms i should run for improving speech signals( As "cheaply" as possible)

There are no constraints for the first requirement as it will be done "offline". But I'm inteding to do the second "on the fly", So i need algorithms which will do its job as economically as possible. In the second case, dedicated DSP hardware may or may not be available. I've to explore both options.

Comment: You need to define more precisely what you mean by "improving" speech.  What is your baseline for comparison?

Comment: I'm looking for [1] "speech" clarity, [2] Noise Reduction, [3]intelligent amplification(Amplifying low sounds but keeping intact the higher amplitudes)
[4]Acoustic Noise Cancellation